# Customize category URL

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting, urls

I've searched around and have not found the answers im looking for. By default I have:

- example.com/blog (blog archive)
- example.com/blog/entry (single entry)
- example.com/blog/category/announcements (single taxonomy view)

Now I've created a custom post type & taxonomy (categories) to go along with it, but I'm having trouble mirroring the blog's URL structure. For example my goal is:

- example.com/talks (talks archive)
- example.com/talks/entry (single talk entry)
- example.com/talks/category/support (single taxonomy view)

Here is what I have so far:

```
function uc_add_talks_post_type() {
  $talks_labels = array(
    'name'                => 'Talks',
    'singular_name'       => 'Talk',
    'all_items'           => 'All Talks',
     …
  );

  $talks_args = array(
    'labels'             => $talks_labels,
    'public'             => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui'            => true,
    'menu_position'      => 5,
    'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'talks', 'with_front' => false ),
    'has_archive'        => 'talks',
  );

  $talks_cat_args = array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'labels' => array(
      'name' => 'Talk categories',
      'singular_name' => 'Talk category',
      …
    ),
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array(
      'slug' => 'talks',
      'with_front' => false
    ),
  );

  register_post_type( 'uc_talks', $talks_args );
  register_taxonomy( 'uc_talks_cat', array('uc_talks'), $talks_cat_args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'uc_add_talks_post_type');
```

Comment: What is your specific trouble? What is not happening/working with this code that you expect to work?

Comment: I can't figure out how to get the talk categories URL to be example.com/talks/category/support. It's currently example.com/talks/support and that is returning a 404 (i do have a taxonomy-uc_talks_cat.php) page. It's not really that I expect that URL to be working, I know im missing something, but i've tried a bunch of things and can't figure out what I should be doing.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out by reading [this article](https://mondaybynoon.com/revisiting-custom-post-types-taxonomies-permalinks-slugs/). It was very simple, all I had to do was:

1. Change the `$talks_cat_args[rewrite][slug]` from `'talks'` to `'talks/category'` (which I had tried before) but missed…
2. Make sure `register_taxonomy` is before `register_post_type`.

Read the article, but it's basically because of "how WP_Rewrite works as the process of deciphering permalinks is, in a way, top-down"

For posterities sake here is the final code (with a little reformatting). I can't argue that this is the best or cleanest way to do this, cause I'm pretty new to WordPress & PHP, but it's working thus-far.

```
 $talks_labels = array(
    'name'                => 'Talks',
    'singular_name'       => 'Talk',
    'all_items'           => 'All Talks',
    'add_new'             => 'Add new',
    'add_new_item'        => 'Add new Talk',
    'edit_item'           => 'Edit Talk',
    'new_item'            => 'New Talk',
    'view_item'           => 'View Talk',
    'search_items'        => 'Search Talks',
    'not_found'           => 'No Talks found',
    'not_found_in_trash'  => 'No Talks found in Trash',
  );

  $talks_args = array(
    'labels'             => $talks_labels,
    'public'             => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui'            => true,
    'menu_position'      => 5,
    'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'talks', 'with_front' => false ),
    'has_archive'        => 'talks',
  );


  $talks_cat_labels= array(
    'name'              => 'Talk categories',
    'singular_name'     => 'Talk category',
    'search_items'      => 'Search talk categories',
    'all_items'         => 'All talk categories',
    'parent_item'       => 'Parent talk category',
    'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent talk category:',
    'edit_item'         => 'Edit talk category',
    'update_item'       => 'Update talk category',
    'add_new_item'      => 'Add new talk category',
    'new_item_name'     => 'New talk category name',
  );

  $talks_cat_args = array(
    'hierarchical' => true,            
    'labels' => $talks_cat_labels,
    'show_admin_column' => true, 
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array(
      'slug' => 'talks/category',
      'with_front' => false
    ),
  );

  register_taxonomy( 'uc_talks_cat', array('uc_talks'), $talks_cat_args );
  register_post_type( 'uc_talks', $talks_args );
```